# Continuous-time Markov processes and discontinuous transition probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

Are there any continuous-time Markov processes in which transition probabilities are **discontinuous** functions over time?
Discontinuity does not enable any deep mathematical analysis of the process (such as transition rates).Is this the reason why we do not study such processes or is there anything fundamentally wrong with transition probabilities being discontinuous?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making the transition rates $\lambda_{ij}(t)$ discontinuous functions of $t$, so long as you can still integrate with respect to $t$.  Suppose we visit a state $i$ at time $t$.  Then for each possible next-state $j$ in the state space $S$,  we generate mutually independent random variables $\{X_{ij}(t)\}_{j \in S}$ with marginal distributions $P[X_{ij}(t)\leq x] = 1-e^{-\int_{t}^{t+x}\lambda_{ij}(\tau)d\tau}$ for all $x>0$. Whichever of these random variables is the smallest determines the next state we visit, and the time of the visit.

Comment: @Michael The question asks for discontinuous transition probabilities. Even discontinuous transition rates do not allow that.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your comments.The question is about transition probabilities,as Did commented.And in a way,the heart of the question is the mathematically rich comment of yous -you wouldn't be able to provide such analysis if transition probabilities were discontinuous,as the path to transition rates would be blocked.

Comment: @Did That's right,Did.Any ideas about the question,even in the sphere of a "philosophical" discussion?

Comment: Here is a basic fact: the transition probabilities of any Markov process are continuous hence asking for discontinuous transition probabilities forces to leave the Markov setting and the convenient tools available in it (even the notion itself of transition probability should be modified). To be more specific, one would need to know which type of (non Markov) process you have in mind.

Comment: *homogenous. $ $

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple, if somewhat artificial, example of a Markov process $X=(X_t)$ with state space $\Bbb R$ and discontinuous (in time) transition probabilities. Started at $x<0$, $X$ moves deterministically to the right until time $-x$, when it jumps to $+1$ and moves thereafter as a three-dimensional Bessel process (the radial part of a three-dimensional Brownian motion). Started at $x\ge 0$, $X$ evolves as a three-dimensional Bessel process. Let $P_tf(x):=\Bbb E^x[f(X_t)]$ for $t\ge 0$, $x\in \Bbb R$, and $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ bounded and continuous. (The superscript $x$ on the expectation indicates the starting point $x=X_0$.) Observe that for $x<0$,
$$
\lim_{t\uparrow -x}P_tf(x) = \lim_{t\uparrow -x}f(x+t)=f(0),
$$
while 
$$
P_{-x}f(x)=f(1).
$$
Thus $t\mapsto P_tf(x)$ will (for $x<0$) be discontinuous at $t=-x$ unless $f(0)=f(1)$.

This process $X$ is a strong Markov process, but it isn't a Feller process.